# What does this error mean when building and Android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing an Android application in Eclipse but it shows the following in my console when I clean, build and debug it:

```
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] ------------------------------
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] Android Launch!
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] adb is running normally.
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] Performing com.lk.lankabell.android.activity.LoginPage activity launch
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'test'
[2013-06-05 09:05:37 - TSRAndroidSystem] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'test'
[2013-06-05 09:05:49 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-06-05 09:05:49 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-06-05 09:05:51 - TSRAndroidSystem] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-06-05 09:05:51 - TSRAndroidSystem] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-06-05 09:06:42 - TSRAndroidSystem] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-05 09:06:42 - TSRAndroidSystem] Uploading TSRAndroidSystem.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-06-05 09:06:44 - TSRAndroidSystem] Installing TSRAndroidSystem.apk...
[2013-06-05 09:07:13 - TSRAndroidSystem] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2013-06-05 09:07:13 - TSRAndroidSystem] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2013-06-05 09:07:13 - TSRAndroidSystem] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.lk.lankabell.android.activity' in a shell.
[2013-06-05 09:07:13 - TSRAndroidSystem] Launch canceled!
```

My emulator is running though.

Is it an error, a warning or is it saying that I have to unlock my android emulator screen?

Comment: first uninstall your application from emulator, then try again..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this Scenario was oocured for me many times when i use phone for testing my application

This is because you had installed `TSRAndroidSystem` alredy in your phone  .Te error occur because the app that installed in your phone  uses differnt `debug keystore` that present in your system .

But in your case it happened in emulator . It's really wiered to me .

Did you directly insatlled the `TSRAndroidSystem.apk` developed in another system in your emulator ??

Any way i thing by un-installing the alredy installed app from your Emulator . Then run your project so that the app will be signed with `debug keystore` of your system hope this will sove your issue

Answer (score 7):

This normally happens when you develop on multiple computers.

When you install an application from Eclipse it uses your debug keystore to sign the application. Different computers have different debug keystores (they are just generated automatically), so you have to fully remove the app from your device before installing it again.

Not sure why this would happen on the emulator, but just fully remove the app from the emulator and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It means you need to uninstall the app from the device that you had previously installed the last time you launched it.

Answer (score 1):

That error usually occurs when you have another application with the same package name installed on the device. In your case `com.lk.lankabell.android`.

It can also happen when you develop on multiple computers which means different debug keys in which case the application with the same package is the one you try to install. But since you are using an emulator this cannot be the case.

In either case: go to `Settings > Apps` on your emulator or phone and uninstall the app with that particular package name and try again. And always make sure to choose unique package names to prevent this from happening.